# how to Display only first bar when condition is True

Tags: pine-script

I am new to coding and I want to know how to write a code to display result ONLY FIRST BAR when condition true. Right now, my code displays every single bar when the condition is True.

condition:
if ema(5) > ema(10) and RSI > 50 then display Label "buy" else sell

```
//@version=4

study("EMA", overlay=true)

ema5= ema(close, 5)
ema10 = ema(close,10)
rsi = rsi(close, 14)

plot(ema5, color=color.green)
plot(ema10, color=color.red)


if ema5 > ema10 and rsi > 50 
    label.new(bar_index, na, "buy", color=color.green, textcolor=color.white, style=label.style_labelup, yloc=yloc.belowbar)


if ema5 < ema10 and rsi < 50
    label.new(bar_index, na, "sell", color=color.red, textcolor=color.white, style=label.style_labeldown, yloc=yloc.abovebar)
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
//@version=4

study("EMA", overlay=true)

ema5= ema(close, 5)
ema10 = ema(close,10)
rsi = rsi(close, 14)

var label buy = na
if ema5 > ema10 and rsi > 50 and buy == na
    buy := label.new(bar_index, na, "buy", color=color.green, textcolor=color.white, style=label.style_labelup, yloc=yloc.belowbar)

var label sell = na
if ema5 < ema10 and rsi < 50 and sell == na
    sell := label.new(bar_index, na, "sell", color=color.red, textcolor=color.white, style=label.style_labeldown, yloc=yloc.abovebar)
```